# MySQL directly gives results, though none through script

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on script, which is in this code part retrieving info from MySQL server but:

That's command being executed:

Executing command by this code, gives no results:

```
$zapytanie = "SELECT * FROM all_orders WHERE (ID = '2' OR ID = '3' OR ID = '5' OR ID = '7' OR ID = '9' OR ID = '10' OR ID = '11' OR ID = '15' OR ID = '17' OR ID = '18' OR ID = '19' OR ID = '22' OR ID = '24' OR ID = '25' OR ID = '26' OR ID = '27' OR ID = '28' OR ID = '29' OR ID = '30' OR ID = '31' OR ID = '32' OR ID = '35' OR ID = '36' OR ID = '37' OR ID = '38' OR ID = '39' OR ID = '40' OR ID = '41' OR ID = '45' OR ID = '47' OR ID = '48' OR ID = '49' OR ID = '50' OR ID = '53' OR ID = '54' OR ID = '55' OR ID = '56' OR ID = '57' OR ID = '60' OR ID = '61' OR ID = '62' OR ID = '63' OR ID = '64' OR ID = '65' OR ID = '67' OR ID = '68' OR ID = '69' OR ID = '70' OR ID = '71' OR ID = '72' OR ID = '73' OR ID = '74' OR ID = '75' OR ID = '76' OR ID = '81' OR ID = '82') AND status='sent' ORDER BY ID ASC";

$validate = mysqli_query($con,$zapytanie);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($validate)) {
    $array[$i] = $row[ID];
    $i++;
  }
  print_r($array, true);
```

Results executing directly appears - 1 row:

http://fotteria.pl/uploads/gallery/0/0/ec46b7/319df40409.jpg

I don't really know what's going on there, but as you can see I can retrieve results directly by this command, but no results are coming up when using on this code.

Comment: Do you have something against the `IN()` operator?

Comment: Or against integers to represent integer values in id fields ?

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump `$validate` after `$validate = mysqli_query($con,$zapytanie);` line? How does it looks like?

Comment: Your code's unquoted `$row[ID]` indicates to me that you don't have `error_reporting` turned up, as it would be complaining about an unknown constant in every loop iteration.  Please turn it up and display errors on screen, as you might find some unexpected stuff `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Always do this in development...

Comment: @Barmar Technically `IN()` is a function, not an operator :-]

Comment: WHERE all these IDs come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print_r($array, true);
```

is your problem

```
$zapytanie = "SELECT IN FROM all_orders WHERE ID IN(2,3,5...) AND status='sent' 
              ORDER BY ID ASC";
$array = array();
$result = mysqli_query($con,$zapytanie);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $array[] = $row['ID'];
}
print_r($array);
```

Comment: A somewhat funny fact. I managed to write several answers today, some of them require deep knowledge or even some code to write and debug first. But only spotting a silly typo was distinguished with some upvotes. This site indeed all about silly typos and spotting them.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems:

1. $row[ID] should be $row['ID'], since ID is not a numerical value.
2. the "true" in the print_r means print_r will not output anything, but just return the result.

Answer (score -1):

Just Maybe this is an option:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM all_orders");

echo "<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th> ( enter variable here) </th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['( enter variable here) '] . "</td>";
  echo '<td><input type="hidden" class="entryid" name="id" value='.$row['ID'].'
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";


mysqli_close($con);
```

This is not neccessarely better becuz I don't look up through ID (auto-increment) but it worked for me!